# Get info from QR code detecting with flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm making an app which scan a QR code and get the version and error correcting level info of it.
How to deal with it.

---

I tried multiple plugins but i didn't found effective one that can get the version and the error corecting level of the code at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: Please share some code from your project, where exactly you are facing a problem, and what is the error you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Please see these links to get you started.

[Building Flutter QR Code Generator, Scanner, and Sharing App](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-flutter-qr-code-generator-scanner-and-sharing-app-703e73b228d3)

[QRCode Flutter](https://flutterawesome.com/tag/qrcode/)

There are many other links available. It's always better to try something first then post your problems here.

Answer (score 0):

The version and error correcting level info are what i asked for..